# QGIS Override MapTool Python

Tags: qgis, python

**My goal is to reuse the default edits tool of QGIS in a custom App.**
But I would like to modify some behavior with those tools.

For instance, the MapTool beside the Edit Node Action.[image]

```
iface.actionNodeTool()
```

When I activate the tool with the GUI I can get the tool beside the QAction with:

```
iface.mapCanvas().mapTool()
```

Give me this:

```
<qgis._gui.QgsMapTool object at 0x0000000011167A60>
```

Does that mean this component inherits directly from the QgsMapTool ?
And we cannot reuse or override the logic ?

If I want the same behavior (and more) I have to rewrite all the logic ?

Last example for illustrate, with the polygon edit tool.[image]

For terminate a feature, you have to right click. I like all the tool behavior, but I would like to terminate with a double click. Do I have to rewrite a tool for QgsMapTool or can I reuse the existing tool ?
[image]

If you have any ideas